# PHP Ping on Ubuntu

Tags: php, networking, ubuntu, ping

I am having trouble getting PHP to ping a local computer. I just want to be able to check if the computer is awake or not.

I have seen numerous methods to ping while searching, but none seem to work for me. I believe this is because on Ubuntu, ping requires root privileges, which PHP does not have. Most examples use some form of

```
exec("ping ".$ip);
```

but any method would be okay with me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system, the command `ls -l /bin/ping` shows:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 34716 2010-11-15 09:08 /bin/ping
```

This means that although "ping" is owned by root, all users can execute it.
You should try with the following PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
<?php 
$result = exec("/bin/ping -c 1 -W 1 127.0.0.1"); 
echo "result=".$result."\n";
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviuously, you should replace "127.0.0.1" with a valid IP address for your network.
The `-c 1` option stops pinging after sending one packet, as described in the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping):

> **-c** count
> Stop after sending count ECHO_REQUEST packets.
>   With deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the timeout
>   expires.

The `-W 1` option forces ping to stop if it does not get a response after one second:

> **-W** timeout
>   Time to wait for a response, in seconds.
> The option affects only  timeout in absense of any responses, otherwise ping waits for two RTTs.

Comment: `ls -l /bin/ping` gets me
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34948 2008-11-13 21:43 /bin/ping`
so i appear to have the some privileges as you.

However, running the PHP code you provided me just comes up with "result=", even for the 127.0.0.1 localhost.

testing the same exec function in terminal give me:
`/bin/ping -c 1 -W 1 127.0.0.1`
`PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.`
`64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms`

with additional statistics.

I seem to have same problem as before, this method doesn't seem to work for me, and I don't know why.

Comment: No, your permissions on the "ping" executable are different from mine. I have `-rwsr-xr-x`, while you have `-rwxr-xr-x`. You should execute this command: `sudo chmod u+s /bin/ping`, then retry to ping from the PHP script.

Comment: wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that. You are a life safer, it works now. Thanks a ton, I've been trying to get this working for a couple weeks now!